# DDR3 clock xilinx MIG

Tags: memory, ip, clock, vivado

I am trying to read and write from DDR3 ram, connected to my FPGA Artix-7. I am using MIG-7, to build my IP in Vivado 2015.1.

The IP needs has two input clocks, reference clock and system clock. 
I use internal IP (FPGA internal PLL) to make a 400 Mhz clock and I have connected the clock to them.

The circuit doesn't work and *ui_clk_sync_rst* is '0', and *init_calib_complete* never goes high!

How should I assign these clock signals?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;


entity Main_Prg is
    Port ( 

               -- Inouts
    ddr3_dq                        : inout std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    ddr3_dqs_p                     : inout std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
    ddr3_dqs_n                     : inout std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);

    -- Outputs
    ddr3_addr                      : out   std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
    ddr3_ba                        : out   std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    ddr3_ras_n                     : out   std_logic;
    ddr3_cas_n                     : out   std_logic;
    ddr3_we_n                      : out   std_logic;
    ddr3_reset_n                   : out   std_logic;
    ddr3_ck_p                      : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
    ddr3_ck_n                      : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
    ddr3_cke                       : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
    ddr3_cs_n                      : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
    ddr3_odt                       : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);


           LEDV6 : out STD_LOGIC;
           LEDV7 : out STD_LOGIC;
           clk25 : in STD_LOGIC);
end Main_Prg;

architecture Behavioral of Main_Prg is


component Clock_IP
port
 (
  clk_in           : in     std_logic;
  clk_out          : out    std_logic
 );
end component Clock_IP;


  component DDR3_RAM
    port(
      ddr3_dq       : inout std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
      ddr3_dqs_p    : inout std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
      ddr3_dqs_n    : inout std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);

      ddr3_addr     : out   std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
      ddr3_ba       : out   std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
      ddr3_ras_n    : out   std_logic;
      ddr3_cas_n    : out   std_logic;
      ddr3_we_n     : out   std_logic;
      ddr3_reset_n  : out   std_logic;
      ddr3_ck_p     : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
      ddr3_ck_n     : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
      ddr3_cke      : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
      ddr3_cs_n     : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
      ddr3_odt      : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
      app_addr                  : in    std_logic_vector(27 downto 0);
      app_cmd                   : in    std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
      app_en                    : in    std_logic;
      app_wdf_data              : in    std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
      app_wdf_end               : in    std_logic;
      app_wdf_wren              : in    std_logic;
      app_rd_data               : out   std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
      app_rd_data_end           : out   std_logic;
      app_rd_data_valid         : out   std_logic;
      app_rdy                   : out   std_logic;
      app_wdf_rdy               : out   std_logic;
      app_sr_req                : in    std_logic;
      app_ref_req               : in    std_logic;
      app_zq_req                : in    std_logic;
      app_sr_active             : out   std_logic;
      app_ref_ack               : out   std_logic;
      app_zq_ack                : out   std_logic;
      ui_clk                    : out   std_logic;
      ui_clk_sync_rst           : out   std_logic;
      init_calib_complete       : out   std_logic;
      -- System Clock Ports
      sys_clk_i                      : in    std_logic;
      -- Reference Clock Ports
      clk_ref_i                                : in    std_logic;
      sys_rst             : in std_logic
      );
  end component DDR3_RAM;


    signal  cntr01  :   std_logic_vector(50 downto 0) := (others=>'0');
    signal  cntr02  :   std_logic_vector(50 downto 0) := (others=>'0');
    signal  ck25    :   std_logic ;
    signal  ck400   :   std_logic ;

  signal app_addr                    : std_logic_vector(27 downto 0) := (others=>'0') ;
  signal app_cmd                     : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)  := (others=>'0') ;
  signal app_en                      : std_logic := '0';
  signal app_wdf_data                : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0) := (others=>'0') ;
  signal app_wdf_end                 : std_logic := '0';
  signal app_wdf_wren                : std_logic := '0';
  signal app_rd_data                 : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0) := (others=>'0') ;
  signal app_rd_data_end             : std_logic;
  signal app_rd_data_valid           : std_logic;
  signal app_rdy                     : std_logic;
  signal app_wdf_rdy                 : std_logic;
  signal app_sr_active               : std_logic;
  signal app_ref_ack                 : std_logic;
  signal app_zq_ack                  : std_logic;
  signal clk                         : std_logic;
  signal rst                         : std_logic;
  signal init_calib_complete_s       : std_logic;
  signal app_rdy_i                   : std_logic;
  signal app_wdf_rdy_i               : std_logic;
  signal app_rd_data_valid_i         : std_logic;
  signal init_calib_complete_i       : std_logic;
  signal app_addr_i                  : std_logic_vector(27 downto 0) := (others=>'0') ;



begin


ck25 <= clk25 ;

U1: process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
         cntr01 <= cntr01 + 1 ;
    end if;
end process;

--U2: process(ck400)
--begin
--    if rising_edge(ck400) then
--        if cntr02(28) = '0' then
--            cntr02 <= cntr02 + 1 ;
--        end if;    
--    end if;
--end process;

Uclk:   Clock_IP    port map
(      clk_in => ck25,
       clk_out=> ck400); 

LEDV6 <= init_calib_complete_i ; -- cntr01(25); 
LEDV7 <= cntr01(25);






  u_DDR3_RAM : DDR3_RAM
      port map (
       -- Memory interface ports
       ddr3_addr                      => ddr3_addr,
       ddr3_ba                        => ddr3_ba,
       ddr3_cas_n                     => ddr3_cas_n,
       ddr3_ck_n                      => ddr3_ck_n,
       ddr3_ck_p                      => ddr3_ck_p,
       ddr3_cke                       => ddr3_cke,
       ddr3_ras_n                     => ddr3_ras_n,
       ddr3_reset_n                   => ddr3_reset_n,
       ddr3_we_n                      => ddr3_we_n,
       ddr3_dq                        => ddr3_dq,
       ddr3_dqs_n                     => ddr3_dqs_n,
       ddr3_dqs_p                     => ddr3_dqs_p,
       init_calib_complete            => init_calib_complete_s,
       ddr3_cs_n                      => ddr3_cs_n,
       ddr3_odt                       => ddr3_odt,
-- Application interface ports
       app_addr                       => app_addr,
       app_cmd                        => app_cmd,
       app_en                         => app_en,
       app_wdf_data                   => app_wdf_data,
       app_wdf_end                    => app_wdf_end,
       app_wdf_wren                   => app_wdf_wren,
       app_rd_data                    => app_rd_data,
       app_rd_data_end                => app_rd_data_end,
       app_rd_data_valid              => app_rd_data_valid,
       app_rdy                        => app_rdy,
       app_wdf_rdy                    => app_wdf_rdy,
       app_sr_req                     => '0',
       app_ref_req                    => '0',
       app_zq_req                     => '0',
       app_sr_active                  => app_sr_active,
       app_ref_ack                    => app_ref_ack,
       app_zq_ack                     => app_zq_ack,
       ui_clk                         => clk,
       ui_clk_sync_rst                => rst,
-- System Clock Ports
       sys_clk_i                       => ck400,
-- Reference Clock Ports
       clk_ref_i                      =>  ck400,
        sys_rst                        => cntr02(28)
        );
-- End of User Design top instance


end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Lets see some verilog!

Comment: I have uploaded the code here:
http://textuploader.com/arkhp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sys_clk can't be generated under the FPGA. You have to provide it from an external oscillator.
Follow the example of [AC701 Artix7 kit](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/ac701/ug952-ac701-a7-eval-bd.pdf), it use a differential clock at 200Mhz.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have an ocsillator that is not not suitable for your MIG, you can create a clock with two outputs (from Clocking Wizard) and then connect the 1st clock to MIG's system clock and the 2nd clock to reference clock.

In MIG's settings reference and system clocks must be set to "No Buffer" type.

Reference clock must be 200 MHz. If system clock is 200 MHz, then you can select "Use system clock".